# Check if the field contains certain values

Tags: solr

I have documents who contains a lot of values, as:

```
"mydata":["699 50000 50002 50031",
      "699 878",
      "200000 200150 200170 200171",
      "200000 200150 200170 200172",
      "200000 200150 200170 200175",
      "200000 200150 200170 200176",
      "200000 200150 200170 200174",
      "200000 200150 200170 200173",
      "200000 200150 200170 200177",
      "200000 200150 200190 200191",
      "200000 200150 200190 200181"],
```

And I want to select the documents according to two select cases:

1/ The mydata field contains values between 200000 to 299999
I bring my documents with the

```
mydata:[200000 TO 299999]
```

clause. no problems.

2/ The mydata field contains values 1 to 199999
but if I do:

```
mydata:[1 TO 199999]
```

I bring back 0 documents, yet the mydata contains the values 699 50000 50002 50031 699 878 who are ok, so this document should be return.

How can I do that ? Thanks for help

Comment: You need to index the field as a multivalued integer field; if you can't change the input format (i.e. it's from CSV or something similar), use a update processor chain to split the content on whitespace before it is seen by the field. An update processor chain runs before the content is "seen" by the actual update, so you can change the submitted content. If you control the indexing process, submit the field as an array with the value pre-split.